# Unlock Windows 10 with Bluetooth proximity?

Tags: windows, security, bluetooth, windows-10

There used to be an application or two which would cause Windows to lock and unlock based on the proximity of a paired Bluetooth device.

These apps don't seem to exist anymore, and I'm surprised this feature isn't more commonly used (Android and iOS both seem to allow unlocking a phone/tablet when near a specific smartwatch).

Is there any way to do this currently?

Comment: These were third-party applications I presume?  Windows Authentication really has not changed, if it worked before, it should still work.

Comment: @Ramhound - indeed they were third party; the problem is that BTProximity uses a networked installer, and the author discontinued it and pulled down everything, so it's no longer possible to install.

Comment: You sort of answered your own question.

Comment: I was wondering if there were any other ways to do it...

Comment: Bluetooth can bridge quite some distance. It's not suitable for detection of presence.

Answer (score 4):

I found this program on SourceForge: [BtProx](http://sourceforge.net/projects/btprox/?source=typ_redirect).

It's open source, and although hasn't been updated since 2012, it works in Windows 10 (tested on build 11082).

It can lock your workstation, but can't unlock it (very difficult, as it goes against one of the reasons for the lock screen).  Having said that, it gives the option to launch programs on lock and unlock, so you could implement your own system (say a custom screensaver/lock).

[image: BtProx Program Window]

Comment: what do we put in lock command... i dont get it

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest: [Windows creators update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/04/11/whats-new-in-the-windows-10-creators-update/)

You can find the Dynamic Lock toggle in **Settings. Go to Accounts > Sign-in options** and you’ll see it listed there. You can toggle the setting On or Off, but that’s it. There are no other settings, and it doesn’t seem to do anything at the moment.

[More info:](https://betanews.com/2017/01/12/dynamic-lock-windows-10/)

Comment: +1 Just turned this on, and seems to work well.  Locks my PC after I move about 15 feet away.  Wish there was a proximity unlock, though, but for now, I suppose PIN code is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

BtProx and Dynamic Lock only allow locking.

[This program](https://www.gadgetish.com/) does both lock and unlock, notifies your phone if anyone tries to steal your laptop, allows to lock/unlock with your phone fingerprint reader and blocks the screen saver when you are within Bluetooth range.

You'll need to install the program in your PC, an app in your Android phone/smartwach and select a Credential Provider in the lock screen.

Comment: It seems a good program, I installed it but couldn't try it, as it needed the highest end subscription option (more money) to make you able to unlock your PC.